# Probability of remaining lifetime using force of mortality

Tags: probability, statistics, actuarial-science

I've been stuck on this question for the past half hour and still have no idea how to solve it...  I don't think it's supposed to be very difficult but I'm struggling:

There are two independent live which are identical except that one is a smoker and the other is a non-smoker.  It is know that:

1. $\mu_x$ is the force of mortality for non-smokers for $0\le x<\omega$
2. $c\mu_x$ is the force of mortality for smokers for $0\le x<\omega$, where c is a constant, $c>1$

Calculate the probability that the remaining lifetime of the smoker exceeds that of the non-smoker and check for the reasonableness of your answer.

Additional details:

1. To solve the problem we're supposed to denote Z as the age at death with cdf $F_Z(x)$ and pdf $f_Z(z)$ and the survival function defined as $s(x)=1-F_Z(x)$
2. The force of mortality represents the likelihood of the individual aged x dying in the next instant dt i.e. $$\mu_x=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{F_Z(x+\Delta x)-F_Z (x)}{\Delta x(1-F_X (x)) }=\frac{f_Z(x)}{1-F_Z (x) }=\frac{-s' (x)}{s(x)} $$
3. c is a constant and $\omega$ denotes the maximum possible age attained so $F_Z(\omega)=1$
4. We also use $T(x)=Pr(Z-x | x>0)$ to denote the future lifetime

I have not really made much meaningful progress however.

Edit:
Sorry I almost forgot I think the force of mortality should be uniformly distributed between $x$ and $\omega$... i.e. $\mu_{x+t}=\frac{1}{\omega-x-t}$

Comment: Could you define some of the terms and show what you've done so far?

Comment: Yepp sure I'm about to go to bed but I'll update it tomorrow morning when I'm rested. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Ok I've added some details for the definitions hopefully the question makes more sense now!

Comment: Sorry I added another detail which may be crucial to answering this question... thanks!!